# Carrierwave: Dynamically find correct storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm planning to move all locally stored images to AWS S3.

To make the transition as smooth as possible I don't want to migrate in one step. Instead I want the application to check if there's already an image stored in S3. If not then it should fall back to the local file system and get the old one.

Is that possible?

Update:
Here is the setup

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id:     '...',
    aws_secret_access_key: '...',
  }
 config.fog_directory  = Rails.env
 config.fog_public = false
end
```

This is the model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Nothing special at all? Is the setup somehow relevant for a potential solution?

Comment: so you mean check if s3 image is avialable if yes load it if not load the local version of that image?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know much about your setup. could you please update your question and show us your setup, model and bucket "don't forget to remove your credentials"

Answer (score 0):

You can map each setting for Carrierwave at the uploader level too.

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  # define some uploader specific configurations in the initializer
  # to override the global configuration
  def initialize(*)
    super

    self.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',              # required
      :aws_access_key_id      => 'YOURAWSKEYID',     # required
      :aws_secret_access_key  => 'YOURAWSSECRET',    # required
    }
    self.fog_directory = "YOURBUCKET"
  end
end
```

Take a look at the [Carrierwave Wiki Page](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Define-different-storage-configuration-for-each-Uploader.).